# PHP custom router Error 404

Tags: php, routes, url-routing, router

I'm trying to create basic router in PHP,but only the index route works("").

When I try another route,like "login", I get the 404 error.

My router:

```
class Router {

 private $routes = [];

 public function __construct($routes)
 {
     $this->routes = $routes;       
 }

 public function directTo($uri)
 {
     if (array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes)) {

        return $this->routes[$uri];

     } 

     throw new \Exception("Route not found", 1);

 }

}
```

Routes file:

```
return [

  '' => 'controllers/IndexController.php',

  'login' => 'controllers/LoginController.php',

  'register' => 'controllers/RegisterController.php',

  'logout' => 'controllers/LogoutController.php',

];
```

App entry point (index.php):

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use App\Controllers\Router;

$routes = require_once "routes.php";

$uri = trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/');

$router = new Router($routes);

require $router->directTo($uri);
```

I think that the problem might be something about $uri variable in index.php, but I can't pinpoint the problem.

When I hard-code the $uri like this:

```
require $router->directTo("login");
```

it works like a charm.

Comment: Are you using any .htaccess file at all?

Comment: No, I guess thats something I should look into.Thanks for the idea.

Comment: +SpacePhoenix Thanks for the tip,I've solved the problem just by creating .htaccess file and adding: FallbackResource /index.php to it. If you are willing to write a full answer,I'll gladly accept it. Have a nice day!